# If using formGroup in angular 6 some errors are showing

Tags: angular6

By using this in reactive forms

```html
<form #branchForm [formGroup]='branchForm'>
```

I got some errors as

```html
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-body">
        <form #branchForm [ERROR ->][formGroup]='branchForm'>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group"  [ngClass]="): ng:///BranchManagementRoutingModule/BranchManagementComponent.html@63:26
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-body">
        <form #branchForm [ERROR ->][formGroup]='branchForm'>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group"  [ngClass]="): ng:///BranchManagementRoutingModule/BranchManagementComponent.html@63:26
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14830)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:24018)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:24005)
    at compiler.js:23948
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:23948)
    at compiler.js:23858
    at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23857)
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14830)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:24018)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:24005)
    at compiler.js:23948
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:23948)
    at compiler.js:23858
    at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23857)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

I have imported all the necessary modules such as ReactiveFormsModule,Fromgroup etc

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
and included these in imports also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ReactiveFormsModule from @angular/forms
```

Is needed to be imported into your components module and added to your imports as well.

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports ...
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

> To fix this error, you just need to `import ReactiveFormsModule from @angular/forms` in your module.